# Have problems with insert to TableLayoutControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I need to have control which provides next functionality:

- First N rows contains some info and button to remove itself
- Last row contains add button.  Newly added rows must be inserted before row with add button.

But i have some problem with insert. Sometimes it inserts correctly, but often it is not.

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Insert(tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1, new  RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
var control = CreateControl();

tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(control,0,tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1);
tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
```

What i done wrong?

Example of error: [image]

Comment: http://grabilla.com/03316-3506bf4c-f111-4083-a2c1-115418b75216.png some sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Add Button object is called btnAdd, I think this should work -

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();

tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Insert(tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1, new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(btnAdd, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1);

var control = CreateControl();
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(control, 0, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 2);
tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
```